# room migration failure fallback android

Tags: android, android-room

For android's room migrations, are there any methods or techniques that allow a fallback for if for some odd reason (not missing schema - I already know about the `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` method) a migration fails? i.e. to nuke and recreate the entire db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the whole thing in a try catch block.

Source: used it for a migration with 20m+ users. No crashes directly related to the migration

Answer (score 0):

There is a `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` method available on the room builder class that is used to generate the database. (`Room.databaseBuilder`)

The method explains itself :) It removes the data in Room when the migration fails

```
Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MyDatabase.class, "database-name")
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build();
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbackToDestructiveMigration()

According to the documentation `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` only triggers if the migration schema is not found. I'm looking for a solution for a migration fallback for if migration fails for other reasons. Does anything exist?